# What triggers (or generates) KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE?

Tags: android, keyevent, headset, android-audiomanager

The documentation for [KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#ACTION_MULTIPLE) says:

> "multiple duplicate key events have occurred in a row, or a complex
>   string is being delivered. If the key code is not {#link
>   KEYCODE_UNKNOWN then the {#link getRepeatCount() method returns the
>   number of times the given key code should be executed. Otherwise, if
>   the key code is KEYCODE_UNKNOWN, then this is a sequence of characters
>   as returned by getCharacters()."

But it doesn't say **how** to actually generate that event.

1. I tried (rapidly) **double-clicking** the headset's Pause/Play button, but all I receive is ordinary ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN.
2. I also tried **pressing and holding down** the headset's Pause/Play button, but all I receive is ordinary ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN.

How do I generate a [KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#ACTION_MULTIPLE) (as a user, using a headset control)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android's [BaseMovementMethod](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/method/BaseMovementMethod.java) includes code for handling `ACTION_MULTIPLE` so presumably the event is generated for key auto-repeat when the user holds down an arrow key.

Comment: Thanks! That's the first answer that actually provide some authoritative reference. I haven't been able to test an arrow key because I don't have one? Where do I find the arrow key on a typical smartphone with a touch screen only? +1 for now (will accept if that's the best answer around).

Comment: A typical smartphone _doesn't_ have this hardware.  A typical smartphone also doesn't have a keyboard, mouse, trackpad, or dpad, to list some of the other input devices Android supports.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I would think that ACTION_MULTIPLE would probably be triggered by actual buttons on a blutooth keyboard for instance. I think that the reason you're just getting ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN is because those are the pre-defined KeyEvents for your headset controls. I hope this helps. :)